Combinatorial optimization problem via VQE instead of QAOA
I'm studying about the hybrid quantum algorithms and I have a question about the VQE and QAOA.
It seems like QAOA is a part of VQE that use a certain ansatz for solving combinatorial optimization problem by finding a highest computational basis that can be found from the lowest energy of a given Ising Hamiltonian.
Let's suppose that I have a quantum computer that can prepare aribitrary quantum states.
If we use the VQE to solve the combinatorial optimization problem with this computer, can't we get the same solution as can be obtained from the QAOA?
If so, is there a reason why people are only focusing on the QAOA for the combinatorial optimization problem solving?

VQE is more general algorithm allowing to look for ground state of a general Hamiltonian. On the other hand, QAOA is intended only for finding ground state of Ising Hamiltonian. So, we can say that QAOA is "subset" of VQE
The reason why people often focus on QAOA instead of VQE is that Ising Hamiltonian is related to quadratic unconstrained binary optimization (QUBO) having wide application in business (for example: traveling salesman problem, quadratic assignment problem, portfolio optimization, many logistic problems etc.). Despite that QAOA was originally intended for QUBO, it can be adapted also for binary optimization of higher degree (see here).
For a brief discussion on the difference between these two techniques, see this paper, pg. 9. A description of QAOA and its application for QUBO problems is discussed here, pg. 20. In the papers you can also find several references which can help you in deeper understanding of both algorithms. Disclaimer: I am author of these papers.

I don't know much about this stuff. I have a question. So, are finding the ground state of Ising Hamiltonian and QUBO problems mathematically equivalent? Are they the same class of problems?

@FDGod: Yes, they are both NP-hard problems. One can be translated to another with simple linear transformation. See for example here: https://arxiv.org/abs/1302.5843

My first question is whether it is possible to get the same solution of the Ising model using VQE instead of QAOA if we have a quantum computer that can perform arbitrary state preparation. If QAOA is subset of VQE, I think it is possible and I don't know why people are just only focusing on QAOA for solving the Ising model instead of using VQE.

@William: Yes, the results should be same in case of QAOA and VQE. You can see this in result section of my first linked paper (pg. 16). In my case, I even found out that VQE needs less iterations than QAOA. However, I solved only a toy problem (six variables), so I would not draw strong conclusions from that. Concerning your second question, it is often better to use  an algorithm specialized for your particular problem.  Moreover, there are not only QAOA and VQE for solving Ising model. Please, have a look at quantum annealers (provided by company D-Wave).

@William: This may help: https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/8566/is-vqe-a-class-of-algorithms-or-a-specific-algorithm

@Martin Vesely Btw, it seems to me that if we have a quantum computer that can prepare any arbitrary states, VQE is way better than QAOA for solving Ising model in terms of the number of parameters to be varied. VQE has a limited number of parameters to be varied while QAOA requires the infinite number of parameters to get a precise solution. What do you think about it?

@William: First, it depends on number of layers how many parameters you have. Both QAOA and VQE can have many layers. However, number of parameters in practice have always to be finite. On second question, as both algorithms are heuristics, I would try both on my problem and pick up the best solution.

@Martin Vesely Ok, so in summary, there is no advantage of using QAOA for solving the combinatorial optimization problem compared to VQE, and both approaches would be expected to give us quantum supremacy, right?

@William: As I mentioned, both are heuristics. This mean that they return only sub-optimal solution. Becuase of this, it has not been proved if they bring about any speed-up. It depends on structure of your problem. Somebody even doubt that it is possible to show any advantage rigorously. We only have empricial evidences for specific problems.   And yes, there is no advantage of QAOA over VQE. As mentioned earlier, I would try both and pick up better solution.  Just note, maybe the reason why people prefer QAOA is the fact that the circuit structure reflects Ising whereas VQE is a black-box.

@Martin Vesely What I understand is that the circuit used in QAOA is the ansatz used specifically for solving Ising model. That's why I think people are more focusing on QAOA for solving the combinatorial optimzation problem. But as I mentioned previously, if we have a quantum computer that can prepare any arbitrary quantum states, VQE can also be used for solving Ising model. But since there are no quantum comptuers that can prepare any arbitrary quantum states, people are making ansatz and that specific ansatz-based VQE algorithm is QAOA. Correct me if I'm wrong or if you have other opinion

@William: We can prepare arbitrary state on a quantum computer now. See a method here: https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0407010. What is more, both VQE and QAOA starts with uniformly distributed superposition which can be easily prepared with Hadamard gate.

@Martin Vesely We cannot. That's why QAOA is suffering making all-to-all connection in Ising model as the number of spins increases. I'm talking about the experimental realization. These days, making arbitrary quantum states from any platforms are extremely difficult due to the limited coherence time and the increasing length of the circuit as the number of qubits increases.

@Wiliam: Ah, I see. From practical point of view you are perfectly right. Theoretically, there is no problem, of course. And, yes that is reason why to use variational algorithm. Despite being heuristics, they are able to run on NISQ processors.

@William: If the answer(s) is ok for you, could you please accept it?

@Martin Vesely Sure, I accept it. Thank you for your reply. In summary, with current quantum computers, we could say that QAOA is more practical than VQE for solving combinatorial optimization problem, right? Also, I have one more question. Is it ok to use VQE for solving combinatorial optimization problem without ansatz if I have a quantum computer that can prepare any arbitrary quantum states? If possible, is there any disadvantage of this method?

@William: I would be careful about assessing which algorithm is better, it depends on structure of task you solve. I am not sure what you mean by VQE without ansatz. The ansatz is in fact the circuit implementing the VQE (see details here: https://www.quera.com/glossary/ansatz). Note that if we had fault-tolerant quantum computer, we would use better algorithms than QAOA and VQE for solving binary optimization problems, e.g. Groover adaptive solver (see here: https://arxiv.org/abs/1912.04088). In comparison with variational algorithms, this one has proved quadratic speed up.

@Martin Vesely I mean since the current quantum computers have no ability to perform arbitrary state preparation, people are making ansatz for the VQE to solve certain problems. But if we have an ability to prepare any arbitrary state, ansatz are not required. So let me ask again. Is it ok to use VQE for solving combinatorial optimization problem without ansatz if I have a quantum computer that can prepare any arbitrary quantum states? If this method is possible, is there any disadvantage of this method?

@William: To be honest, I have never heard about such approach. Try to Google it or you can post another question on this site. Maybe somebody else can help you better.
